# How to get a number of same character and their position in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, extract

I have a string, list and start position:

```
s = "NNDRJGLDFDNJASNJBSA82NNNNNDHDWUEB3J4JJX"
l = [0, ""]
start = 0
```

Now I want to extract all the N's and their positions in the string. What I have tried so far is:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == "N":
        l[0] = i+start
        l[1] = s[i]
```

But I only get the last "N" character from the string. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you always assign to `list[0]` and `list[1]`, you will keep overwriting whatever values you are trying to store. You need to `.append()` to lists to add new items.

Comment: Please don't use `list` as the name of a variable. `list` is the name of a type in python.

Comment: I do not use list in my program. It was only as an example. But I agree I did not think about it when I wrote it.

Comment: `l` is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way using the index method:

```
indices = []
try:
    start = 0
    while True:
        indices.append(s.index('N',start))
        start = indices[-1]+1
except ValueError: pass
```

A solution using numpy:

```
from numpy import array,where
print(where(array(list(s))==N))
```

fixing your own solution:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == "N":
        indices.append(i)
        indices.append(s[i])
```

You don't need start, and I suggest you don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: This answer helped me. Using list was just an example (but a bad idea). I know I should not use it as a variable name. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension combined with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indices of each target character:

```
s = "NNDRJGLDFDNJASNJBSA82NNNNNDHDWUEB3J4JJX"
positions = [i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c == 'N']
>>> positions
[0, 1, 10, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

Comment: My favorite answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you enumerate the list, you can retrieve all the indices where there is a `N`:

```
    s = "NNDRJGLDFDNJASNJBSA82NNNNNDHDWUEB3J4JJX"
    indices = []
    start = 0

    for idx, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == "N":
            indices.append(idx)
    indices
```

#### output:

```
[0, 1, 10, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```